# Algebraically, why is $2xy < x^2 + y^2$

Tags: inequality

I have tried many different examples and found that every time it will work, but I need to know why it will always work.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to know more about related inequalities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 10):

Since all of us knows that a even power is always positive or zero.

Hence, $$(x-y)^2\ge 0$$ and the equality holds when $$x=y$$ so, in case of $$x\neq y$$ $$(x-y)^2>0$$ $$x^2 + y^2- 2xy > 0$$ $$x^2 + y^2 > 2xy$$

Answer (score 6):

because $x^2+y^2-2xy=(x-y)^2\geq 0$ and it is strictly superior to 0 if $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be derived from the simple polynomial expansion of:
$$(x-y)^2 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2$$
Combining with the fact that $n^2, n \in \mathbb{R}$, always yields a zero or positive number.